# How to select a range of dates from a different range of date fields

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I want to select data for a date range that lies within another date range

I have the following table

```
ID  FNAME  LNAME  BEG_EPISODE_DT  END_EPISODE_DT    TRGT_DT
 1  John    G        12/20/16        02/11/17       03/31/17
 2  King    R        11/10/16        12/25/17       03/31/17
 3  Bundt   H        10/19/16        01/16/17       03/31/17
 4  Smith   F        02/16/16        04/08/17       03/31/17
```

Above data shows the episodes of each individual. Episode means the duration from beginning of an episode(BEG_EPISODE_DT) to end of it(END_EPISODE_DT)

I need to select the data such that the episode for each individual lies within 3 months before the target date (TRGT_DT) i.e the episode(BEG_EPISODE_DT or END_EPISODE_DT) should lie between 03/31/17 and 3 months before it

I am trying to use the following logic. But I cant get it to work

```
select * from mytable 
BEG_EPISODE_DT between ((ADD_MONTHS(TRGT_DT,-3), TRGT_DT) or 
END_EPISODE_DT between ((ADD_MONTHS(TRGT_DT,-3), TRGT_DT) or 
BEG_EPISODE_DT = (ADD_MONTHS(TRGT_DT,-3) or TRGT_DT) or
END_EPISODE_DT = (ADD_MONTHS(TRGT_DT,-3) or TRGT_DT)
```

I am looking for the following result

```
ID  FNAME  LNAME  BEG_EPISODE_DT  END_EPISODE_DT    TRGT_DT
 1  John    G        12/20/16        02/11/17       03/31/17
 3  Bundt   H        10/19/16        01/16/17       03/31/17
 4  Smith   F        02/16/16        04/08/17       03/31/17
```

Thanks for the help

Edit: BEG_EPISODE_DT or END_EPISODE_DT can be equal to TRGT_DT or (TRGT_DT - 3 months)

Comment: Although Oracle did buy mysql, on the sw level they are still different products.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation. Should a row with TRGT_DT = 03/31/17 be included, if either BEG_EPISODE_DT or END_EPISODE_DT (or, perhaps, both) is/are between 01/01/2017 and 03/31/2017? Note that 01/01/2017 is not three months before 03/31/2017 (that would be 12/31/2016). Other than that, it is not clear why you subtract TWO months instead of THREE, and then what the point is of subtracting 0 from anything. Also totally unclear why you truncate to beginning of month - there was absolutely no mention of that in your logic. Please clarify.

Comment: Please see Jair's question under mathguy's answer...  Whi is Smith included in the "desired output"? Neither the beginning nor the end date are between 12/31/2016 and 03/31/2017.  Or did you mean something different - you didn't want the specific begin date or end date to be in that interval, but instead, ANY portion of the "episode" to have at least one day in common with that interval? (And if so, then why is King not included in the output as well?)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the keyword `WHERE` for the WHERE clause. Besides that, the `BETWEEN` syntax is much simpler. Something like:

```
where    beg_episode_dt between add_months(trgt_dt, -3) and trgt_dt
      or end_episode_dt between add_months(trgt_dt, -3) and trgt_dt
```

Comment: I also thought of it this way however, this predicate rules out "Smith" which Hemansh included in his desired results, so either this is not the solution he is looking for, or he mistakenly listed Smith as a positive result. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, I didn't catch that. 'Smith' violates the rules as explained by the OP in plain English. I'll add as a Comment.